# Is there a name/interest for regular languages that have a non-ambiguous ending?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, ambiguity

The basic idea is to have one or more symbol that clearly indicate the end. For example:

Non-ambiguous:

> $ab^*c$
>   $(a|b)c$
>    $ab^+c$
>    $ab?c$
>    $a(b|c)$
>    $c(ab)^*ccc$
>    $acc^*d$
>    $abc|bcd$

Ambiguous:

> $abc^*$
>   $abc^+$
>   $abc?$
>   $acc^*$ or $ac^*c$

An alternative definition of a non-ambiguous ending would be that the corresponding DFA can have multiple final states, but none of them can have a outgoing transition.

Comment: Try formalising your definition of non-ambiguous a bit more. For example, would $(abca)^*bc$ be considered non-ambiguous? If and if not, why?

Comment: I have added an alternative definition of a non-ambiguous ending.

Comment: This alternate definition corresponds to prefix-freeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your alternative definition, you're looking for a  language such that $u\in L\Rightarrow \forall v\neq\epsilon, uv\notin L$ (where $\epsilon$ denotes the empty string).

That property defines a useful kind of language in coding, called [**prefix-free codes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix-free_code). Note that this language class doesn't include nor is included in regular languages.

So what you're looking for is the intersection of those two classes. That would be a **prefix-free regular language**.

As for the interest, it seems to have some, since a google search returned [this research paper](http://cs.yonsei.ac.kr/~emmous/papers/tcs_prefixmatching.pdf).

Comment: While prefix-freeness is certainly necessary for "non-ambiguity" as discussed here, is it sufficient? (I think it is; I think your answer should give a justification why it is either.)

Comment: @Raphael I am still not entirely sure what the "non-ambiguity" refers to. $abc|bcd$ is prefix-free, but does is fit the (ironically ambiguous) definition?

Comment: True. I have been ignoring the question itself and focused on the comment: "The basic idea is to have one or more symbol in the pattern that clearly indicate the end."

Comment: The question asks for a property of expressions, not languages.

Comment: Well, I clearly didn't take enough time to ponder the proper wording of my question, but I was not entirely convinced myself of what I was really looking for. At this point, I do think its prefix-freeness (i.e. abc|bcd wouldn't be "ambiguous".)

Comment: @Skeptic Now that your mind is clearer on what you were looking for, you may want to edit your question to make it clearer for future users who stumble on the question (maybe add a bit of context as well). Also, please note that the example $(abca)^*bc$ that I mentioned in a comment on the question *is* prefix-free.

Comment: @Khaur, thanks for the edit and see my comment above. I think reinierpost maybe right to point at determinism.

Comment: @Skeptic With that in mind, I feel that the reinierpost's second definition comes the closest, but with the added constraint that the suffix characters do not occur anywhere in the rest of the language.

Comment: c(ab)*c wouldn't be ambigous.

Comment: @Skeptic Is it because the ending character only appears a fixed number of times?

Comment: Yes. Neither ccc nor c(ab)*ccc would be ambigous.

Comment: c(ab)*c is also prefix-free. It seems to me that prefix-free is what @Skeptic is looking for: when a string ends it's not possible to extend it in any way.

Comment: @Kaveh As Raphael stated, prefix-freeness is necessary, but not all prefix-free regular languages satisfy Skeptic's idea of non-ambiguity.

Comment: Your current formulation only considers "termination patterns" of length one. They can be longer, so you'd want to have a finite set $A$ so that every word in $L$ ends with some $\alpha \in A$, but no word in $L$ has a proper prefix that ends any $\alpha \in A$.

Comment: @Raphael I don't think $a^*ba^*b$ would be considered ambiguous. Maybe by extending the definition to allow for a fixed number of repetitions of the ending pattern: $A=\{(\alpha,n)\}$ such that all words in $L$ have exactly $n$ (non-overlapping) occurrences of $\alpha$ for some $(\alpha,n)\in A$; no word in $L$ has a proper prefix with $n$ (non-overlapping) occurrences of pattern $\alpha$, $\forall(\alpha,n)\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you merely looking for unicity of the *last* character?

In that case, you may mean a property such as:

- the regular expression ends with a character
  (it is `xc` for some expression `x` and character `c`)
- the language described by the regular expression ends with a character
  (it is `Lc` for some regular language `L` and character `c`)

They are different properties: `acc*` meets 2 but not 1.

Or are you looking for a stronger property, that must also apply elsewhere in the expression?

In that case, you may be looking for *determinism*. Determinism is the property of never
having to backtrack and retry while trying to parse (match) a string. It is usually defined assuming parsing from left to right, so it applies to unicity of prefixes rather than suffixes; and it is usually defined for finite automata or context-free grammars rather than regular expressions (but not always - see, e.g., [this paper about deterministic regular expressions](http://wwwconference.org/www2008/papers/pdf/p825-bexA.pdf)).
In that case, you may be looking for a property such as:

- the reverse of the regular expression is deterministic

Here, the reverse is the regular expression obtained by swapping all concatenation arguments, e.g.  the reverses of `ab*c`, `(a|b)c`, `ab+c`, `ab?c`, `abc*`, `a(b|c)`, `abc+`, `abc?` are `cb*a`, `c(a|b)`, `cb+a`, `cb?a`, `c*ba`, `(b|c)a`, `c+ba`, `c?ba`, respectively.

I don't know a name for any of these properties.

Comment: acc* would be "ambiguous".

Comment: `acc*` does not meet the third property; `ac*c` does; so that doesn't tell me which property (if any of these) you mean. Is `acc*d` "ambiguous", according to you?

Comment: both acc* and ac*c would be "ambiguous", but not acc*d.

Comment: OK, then it's none of these. You really have to tell more about what you mean by "ambiguity".

Comment: I realize now that I should have asked about the language and not the expression.

Comment: OK, then I see why the accepted answer is the right one.